# Linux Server where the high security is desired

Tags: linux, security

I am preparing a JAVA program that will be use to monitor a system. The program uses UDP and TCP sockets to receive and send packets over the Internet by using VPN.

I will dedicate a server just for the program. I wonder if there is any Linux server distro that is used for such specific reason that would minimize the port usage, or does not include the unnecessary applications that might cause a security gap?

If the distro does not really matter, could you tell me what are the good applications to increase the security of a server (rather than installing a firewall) and could you explain briefly why?

Comment: There is a certain irony in installing JAVA in a high security system.

Comment: You may be slightly misguided here.  Port usage is not directly correlated with security at all; it's a horrible proxy for security.  When I am hacking into stuff, I will certainly scan for certain services, but mostly I will attack the application intentionally running on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example Debian minimal install is very small and leaves the bloat out. Grab the Net Install image from the [Debian site](http://debian.org/), and don't install anything else than the base system and possibly the ssh/vpn daemon.

[CentOS](http://centos.org/) would give you quite a bit larger base install, but it also does a good job with leaving out the unnecessary crap if you don't install everything it suggests, and also comes with quite tight SELinux rules by default, which in theory gives you better security over the vanilla Linux kernel.

Whatever distro you end up choosing, don't be allergic to firewalls. You can use iptables and allow only the traffic you need to have allowed, deny the rest. That is something you should do anyway, if the security is what you want. With good enough firewall rules things like "Oops, my server got compromised and was used for spamming!" are much more unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Bastille](http://bastille-linux.sourceforge.net/).

It is a script you run on a new host to lock it down.